# MvvmCross ImageView Binding to Byte Array

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am currently trying to bind a Android ImageView to a Byte array that I have setup as my ViewModel.

```
    private Byte[] _currentActivityImage;
    public Byte[] CurrentActivityImage
    {
        get { return _currentActivityImage; }
        set { _currentActivityImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentActivityImage); }
    }
```

I am doing it this way as I am downloading the image as part of the large data download and storing that image data into the database so it's tired directly to a specific record in the table.

I haven't been able to find any information on specifically how to bind the Android ImageView (Or the MvxImageView) to a Byte array or a raw bitmap image.

I saw in one of the posts that Stuart mentioned that capability exists (or maybe I read it wrong.), but was not able to find the correct bindings to use.

(Note: if need be, I can change the property to use Bitmap, but figured that the Byte array might be more cross-platform compatible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture choose sample shows one way to do this - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/PictureTaking

The N+1 N=12,etc CollectABull sample shows another - going via a file https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-12-CollectABull/

Comment: I went ahead and trying to use the first suggestion.   Any idea why this warning would show up in the debugging window?    "MvxBind:Warning: 23.93 Value was not be a valid Bitmap". It's not even getting to the code where the image change takes place.   To be precise, it's occurring on a tab change.

Comment: I should point out that it does work properly.   :)   I'm just curious about the MvxBind:Warning.   Thanks yet again Stuart!

Comment: Sorry - not sure what you mean. Perhaps ask as a new question in a new question. Generally I find it easier to understand and answer full questions - like the one you asked here :) - than short comment-questions.